Deploying Puppeteer on Render.com: "Browser was not found at the configured executablePath"
I'm trying to deploy a Node.js application on Render.com that uses Puppeteer to analyze web pages. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error when trying to launch Puppeteer:
Error during Puppeteer usage: Error: Browser was not found at the configured executablePath (/opt/render/.cache/puppeteer/chrome)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:76:19)
    ...

Context:

I'm using Render.com as a deployment platform.
I'm using Puppeteer to perform simple page analysis, such as visiting https://www.google.com and printing the page title.
I have tried using different versions of Puppeteer, including the latest (^21.0.0) and an older version (19.7.5).
My goal is simply to verify if Puppeteer is installed correctly and if I can get it running in the hosting environment.

Sample Code:
Here's my test.js file, which I use as a test script to verify Puppeteer functionality:
// Import Puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Main function to test Puppeteer
async function testPuppeteer() {
  try {
    // Launch the browser in headless mode with necessary options
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });

    // Create a new page in the browser
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Navigate to an example page
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

    // Get the page title
    const title = await page.title();
    console.log(`Page title (Google): ${title}`);

    // Close the browser
    await browser.close();

    console.log('Puppeteer is working correctly!');
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors if Puppeteer doesn't work correctly
    console.error('Error during Puppeteer usage:', error);
  }
}

// Run the test function
testPuppeteer();

What I've Tried So Far:

Removing the executablePath Option: I tried removing the executablePath option so that Puppeteer can automatically find Chromium.
Different Versions of Puppeteer: I tried both the latest version (^21.0.0) and version 19.7.5.
Postinstall Script: I added a "postinstall": "npx puppeteer install" script to my package.json to ensure Chromium is installed during the build on Render.com.
Environment Variable CHROME_BIN: I set an environment variable CHROME_BIN to /opt/render/.cache/puppeteer/chrome as suggested in various discussions, but without success.

Environment:

Node.js version: v20.15.1.
Hosting platform: Render.com.
Operating system: Linux (Render.com uses a container-based environment).

Problem:
Despite all these changes, I keep getting the error that Chromium is not found at the specified path. It seems Render.com is unable to locate or correctly install the browser.
Questions:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue and found a solution for this kind of error with Puppeteer on Render.com?
Is there something specific I need to do to ensure Puppeteer finds Chromium in a server environment like this?
Any suggestions on how to properly configure Puppeteer on a server that might have restrictions on what can be installed/run?

Thank You!
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I just want to verify that Puppeteer is working correctly on Render.com so I can proceed with developing the project.
package.json File:
{
  "name": "wcag-web-analyzer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "npx puppeteer install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.0",
    "puppeteer": "^21.0.0",
    "axe-core": "^4.5.4"
  }
}


Step 1:
Add a file named puppeteer.config.cjs in the root folder with below code
const {join} = require('path');

/**
* @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
*/
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};

Step 2:
Go to render and click Manual Deploy --> clear build cache and deploy option
reference: reference
